# Backbone.js and RequireJS add JQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, backbone.js

I started my first backbone.js app today and I meet a first problem. I use RequireJS, Backbone and Underscore.

So I wrote this :

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
    text: 'libs/require/text',
    jticker: 'libs/jquery/jquery.jticker'
  }

});

require([
  'app'
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router', // Request router.js
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){
  var initialize = function(){
    Router.initialize();
  }

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

**view app.js call by the default route**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'jticker'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, jticker){
  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("body"),

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).append('bla');
        $(".dialogue").jticker();
    },

  });
  return AppView;
});
```

And i have this problem how can I use [jticker](http://webdev.stephband.info/jticker/) in my view ? Actually it produce an error  without details :

```
$(
[Stopper sur une erreur]    

$(".dialogue").jticker();
```

Comment: What does your template look like? Do you already have .dialogue dom elements on the page?  Also, is jticker wrapped to define a module that can be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to use jticker() after the rendering? because i have the same problems actually in one of my project! If you wait that the DOM completly loaded and then set ".dialogue" with jticker()... just my 5 cents

Comment: I fix it by adding order.js plugin and it looks like it works